# How to use distinct and count with partition by

Tags: sql, distinct, window-functions

I want rows with distinct agt_id along with the count. Following is the query i am currently using but need help to get distinct rows.

```
with cust as
(
SELECT customer_id, cnic
FROM customer
where customer_id 
not in 
(select agent_id from agent
where to_date(created_on) BETWEEN '2020-06-01' AND '2020-06-30')
)

select agt.agent_id, c.customer_id, c.cnic, agt.transaction_type_id, 
agt.transaction_type_name , row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY c.customer_id) AS agent_count
from cust as c
INNER JOIN konnect_ag_transaction_vw agt ON c.cnic= agt.receiver_cnic
where 
agt.status ='PROCESSED'
AND agt.transaction_type_id IN (1,2,3)
```

Current Output using above query:

```
    agt_id  cus_id  Count
1   89563   93587   7
2   89563   93587   7
3   89563   93587   7
4   89563   93587   7
5   89563   93587   7
6   56139   93587   7
7   56139   93587   7
```

**Count** in the above output is the total count of rows with same cus_id where as i want count of agt_id link with same cus_id

Desired output:

```
    agt_id  cus_id  Count
1   89563   93587   2
2   56139   93587   2
```

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: @AsmaDamani . . . I don't believe you.  `row_number()` does not return constant values.  It returns an enumeration.  Something is amiss in your description.  In addition, your result set has three columns, but the query returns more.

Comment: I quess adding a distinct to last select can help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you need a simple group by with count()

```
with cust as
(
SELECT customer_id, cnic
FROM konnect_bb_customer_vw 
where customer_id 
not in 
(select agent_id from konnect_bb_agent_h_vw 
where to_date(created_on) BETWEEN '2020-06-01' AND '2020-06-30')
)

select agt.agent_id, c.customer_id, count(*)
from cust as c
INNER JOIN konnect_ag_transaction_vw agt ON c.cnic= agt.receiver_cnic
where agt.status ='PROCESSED' AND agt.transaction_type_id IN (1,2,3)
group by agt.agent_id, c.customer_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I *suspect* that you want aggregation:

```
select agt.agent_id, c.customer_id, count(*)
from cust c join
     konnect_ag_transaction_vw agt 
     on c.cnic = agt.receiver_cnic
where agt.status = 'PROCESSED' and
      agt.transaction_type_id in (1, 2, 3)
group by agt.agent_id, c.customer_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

using DISTINCT keyword as such

```
select DISTINCT agt.agent_id, c.customer_id, c.cnic, agt.transaction_type_id, 
agt.transaction_type_name , row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY c.customer_id) AS agent_count
from cust as c
INNER JOIN konnect_ag_transaction_vw agt ON c.cnic= agt.receiver_cnic
where 
agt.status ='PROCESSED'
AND agt.transaction_type_id IN (1,2,3)
```